# What is meant by Nagato when she mentions the 'Big Seven'?

Tags: kantai-collection

While attacking the Airfield Princess during the final episode, Nagato and Mutsu turn up midway through the fight. After firing a volley of shells at the target, Nagato says out loud, "Don't underestimate the power of the Big Seven!"

[image: Nagato]

What significance does this hold? There are more than seven ships present, so it's unlikely to be that, and the ship *Nagato* has more than seven guns both in the anime and in real life.

So, what is Nagato referencing when she mentions the 'Big Seven'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a real life reference, and not an in-series one. The 'Big Seven' refers to the 7 battleships that, under the [Washington Naval Conference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Naval_Conference), could mount 16 inch guns. As such, they were the [only battleships to have a 16" armament prior to the outbreak of World War II](http://www.reddit.com/r/Warships/comments/3aazbr/big_seven_battleships_on_wwii/csax38o), and the [dissolution of the treaty.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Naval_Conference#Termination)

Two of the seven ships feature in the Kancolle anime and browser game ([Nagato](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Nagato) and [Mutsu](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Mutsu)), with the other five being from the US and UK. They were:

- [Nagato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_battleship_Nagato) (Imperial Japanese Navy)
- [Mutsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_battleship_Mutsu) (Imperial Japanese Navy)
- [HMS Nelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Nelson_(28)) (Royal Navy)
- [HMS Rodney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Rodney_(29)) (Royal Navy)
- [USS Colorado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Colorado_(BB-45)) (US Navy)
- [USS Maryland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Maryland_(BB-46)) (US Navy)
- [USS West Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_West_Virginia_(BB-48)) (US Navy)

This quote also features in the browser game of *Kantai Collection* during the 'Battle Start' event, where Nagato says the same quote: "Don't underestimate the power of the Big Seven"

Additionally, in the *Kantai Collection* set of the card game *Weiβ Schwarz*, there is a card titled "Do not look down on the power of the Big 7", which features a picture of Nagato, as well as the aforementioned quote:

[image: Card]